# Multiple KML files in same layer ( Google custom maps )

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api, layer-to-kml

Google maps allows you to make a custom map. In each custom map you have "layers" where each layer can contain multiple addresses, locations etc.

You are only allowed to upload one KML file for each layer. I am using KML files to plot a radius around a point on Google Maps. I would like the radius's to be in the same layer however each circle has its own KML file generated from here:

http://kml4earth.appspot.com/tools.html

The way I can see this being solved:

1. Google custom maps has some tools I am not aware of which can do this easier
2. There is a way to join all of these KML files together?

My worry is this has to be updated regularly. i.e new radiuses are added often which means it if not feasible to constantly keep chan ging the KML file.

3. There are other tools/websites/companies out there than can be able to do this more easily.

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling adventurous, you could try using [QGIS](https://qgis.org) to accomplish the job. It would be an easy job to import all your existing .kml files and merge them together, then export again to .kml/kmz or in whatever form or fashion strikes your fancy.

It might not be worth the trouble if this is a one-time project, but if you do anything regularly in Google Earth, it might seriously benefit you to learn how to use proper GIS software.